# LatLng value is not being stored persistently in text file on device

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In my application, the user has two options to place a marker: 1) via the `onMapLongClick` method, and 2) by using a voice command. Both of them work properly, but I noticed a bug that showed up only after several hours of the app being closed via the Home button.

If I wait a few hours and come back to the app, the marker is still there; however, I waited approximately 5-6 hours two separate times and the marker was gone.

What am I doing wrong here? This will be very bad for my users because the app is designed to remember a location, even after hours (or days potentially) of closing the app. It's only one marker at a time, not multiple markers.

Here is where the LatLng objects are stored or retrieved:

**onMapReady:**

```
//Get Lat and Lng of marker and place on map if marker is there && if app has already been launched
            if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", false)) {
                try {
                    FileInputStream input = openFileInput("latlngpoints.txt");
                    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);
                    int sz = din.readInt();
                    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
                        String str = din.readUTF();
                        String[] stringArray = str.split(",");
                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(stringArray[0]);
                        double lon = Double.parseDouble(stringArray[1]);
                        LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                        m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(newLatLng)
                                .title("My Ride")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.custom_marker30x48)));
                        markerDeleted = false;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {}
```

**onActivityResult** for voice recognition button:

```
ArrayList<LatLng> markerLoc = new ArrayList<>();
                                markerLoc.add(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude));

                                try {
                                    FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput("latlngpoints.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(output);
                                    dout.writeInt(markerLoc.size());
                                    for (LatLng point : markerLoc) {
                                        dout.writeUTF(point.latitude + "," + point.longitude);
                                    }
                                    dout.flush();
                                    dout.close();

                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    //Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + e.getMessage());

                                }
```

**onMapLongClick:**

```
ArrayList<LatLng> markerLoc = new ArrayList<>();
                    markerLoc.add(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude));
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput("latlngpoints.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(output);
                        dout.writeInt(markerLoc.size());
                        for (LatLng point : markerLoc) {
                            dout.writeUTF(point.latitude + "," + point.longitude);
                            //Log.d(TAG, "onMapLongClick: " + String.valueOf(point.latitude) + "," +  String.valueOf(point.longitude));
                        }
                        dout.flush();
                        dout.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        //Log.d(TAG, "onMapLongClick: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
```

Am I supposed to do something in my onPause and onResume methods as well? They are pretty much empty except for stopping a sensor listener for a compass, and checking if location services is enabled.

```
    /*
    Stop sensor listeners
    Also check for no Network/GPS
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopSensorListeners();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startSensorListeners();

        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || !locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            //AlertDialog to inform user GPS is off and take them to their Settings activity
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }
    }
```

I will gladly create a database instead if that is a better way to keep persistent storage.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it took me a couple of days to get this to work, but I'm going to post what I came up with in case someone else needs help with this.

First, in my `onMapReady()` I did the following:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (prefs.contains("lat") || prefs.contains("lng")) {
            double lat = prefs.getFloat("lat", 0.0f);
            double lng = prefs.getFloat("lng", 0.0f);
            LatLng resumeLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(resumeLatLng)
                    .title("My Ride")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.custom_marker30x48)));
            markerDeleted = false;
        }
```

In my `onMapLongClick()` method, I did:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor locationEditor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
locationEditor.clear();
locationEditor.putFloat("lat", (float) m.getPosition().latitude).apply();
locationEditor.putFloat("lng", (float) m.getPosition().longitude).apply();
```

I have a clear button that removes the marker, so we gotta take care of that puppy as well. So:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.remove("lat");
editor.remove("lng");
editor.apply();
```

Alright, all good there. Well, what if the user calls the `onPause()` method? Got it:

```
if (!markerDeleted) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor locationEditor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    locationEditor.clear();
    locationEditor.putFloat("lat", (float) m.getPosition().latitude).apply();
    locationEditor.putFloat("lng", (float) m.getPosition().longitude).apply();
}
```

And finally, in my `onResume()` method:

```
if(!markerDeleted) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    double lat = prefs.getFloat("lat", (float) m.getPosition().latitude);
    double lng = prefs.getFloat("lng", (float) m.getPosition().longitude);
    LatLng resumeLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(resumeLatLng)
            .title("My Ride")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.custom_marker30x48)));
    markerDeleted = false;
}
```

Now, I can add a marker, completely close out the app, come back, and my marker is still there.

If I clear the marker, exit the app, and come back, it is not there.

I successfully created Marker persistence using shared preferences, and no databases. :-)